# how to draw lines on plots in matplotlib and exit while loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, while-loop, keyboardinterrupt, ginput

I have a limited experience with programming. I am writing a small application in python using matplotlib which will allow me to digitise segments on a figure to be used to build polygons. I am using ginput() to add points on a graph and draw line but I need to implement a loop in order to have the possibility to draw a variable number of segments according to the feature observed. I am using Jupyter notebook. The applicationso far allows me to add the segments on the plot but I do not manage to exit the while loop. After some research, I saw the possibility to use keyboardinterrupt but it seems not to work. My code looks as follow:

```
t = np.arange(10)
plt.plot(t, np.sin(t)) # just some data on the plot
try:
    while True: # loop to allow me to add multiple lines and plot them 
        xy = plt.ginput(2, show_clicks = True) # set to two as I want just two points and the possibility to draw the line progressively
        x = [p[0] for p in xy]
        y = [p[1] for p in xy]
        line = plt.plot(x,y) #plot the line
        plt.draw()
        plt.show()
        print ('points: ', xy)
except KeyboardInterrupt: # my attempt to exit the while loop but in reality the figure just move to the background and a new figure is generated after 30 secondsf
    pass
```

thanks for the help and regards

Fabio

Comment: I had a similar plan for my figure interaction. I have a for loop, which is sufficiently long and then I just exit it with `break` when the ginput is empty (pressing Esc instead of clicking). This might help people as a workaround..